# MySQL - Query to return repetitive values associated with multi table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Name & Zip, and i want a query to return the zip codes which are having more than 2 plans associated with one different name

```
+------+------+     +------+------+
| TABLE: NAME |     |  TABLE: ZIP |
+------+------+     +------+------+
| Plan | NAME |     | Plan |  ZIP |
+------+------+     +------+------+
|123   |DAVE  |     |123   |11021 |
+------+------+     +------+------+
|456   |TOM   |     |456   |11021 |
+------+------+     +------+------+
|789   |STEVE |     |789   |21021 |
+------+------+     +------+------+
|321   |PAM   |     |321   |78210 |
+------+------+     +------+------+
|654   |JACK  |     |654   |21021 |
+------+------+     +------+------+
```

I would like to get the answers as below

```
+------+------+
| NAME | ZIP  |
+------+------+
|DAVE  | 11021|
+------+------+
|TOM   | 11021|
+------+------+
|PAM   | 21021|
+------+------+
|JACK  | 21021|
+------+------+
```

Can anyone help me to get this query?

Comment: Join the tables and then use `GROUP BY ZIP` and `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) > 2`

Comment: Those zip codes only have 2 different names. 2 is not more than 2, it's exactly equal to 2. Did you mean more than 1?

Comment: yes Barmar, you are right. Need the results having values with more than 1 occurance

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do:

```
SELECT n.NAME, z.ZIP
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIP) AS num
    FROM ZIP
) z
JOIN NAME n ON z.Plan = n.Plan
WHERE z.num > 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DGPmCv8I)

This uses `COUNT()` as a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html). `PARTITION BY` works similarly to `GROUP BY` but without collapsing the rows.

I think your expected result is wrong. It should be DAVE, TOM, STEVE and JACK.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using two `inner join`, first one to join tables based on the Plan, and the second one is to make sure ZIP having 2 or more Plans :

```
with cte as (
  select Zip
  from Zip
  group by Zip
  having count(1) > 1
)
select n.Name, z.Zip
from Name n
inner join Zip z on z.Plan = n.Plan
inner join cte c on c.Zip = z.Zip;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JY6zfd1x)